# Getting cookie stored in Javascript in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to get the cookie,set in JavaScript code, inside a controller method in Ruby on Rails v 4.0 ?

Comment: Just to clarify, "get the cookie set in JavaScript code inside a controller method" doesn't make sense.  The cookie can be set in the controller, which effectively adds it to the http response sent back to the browser.  In the browser, the cookie can be read with javascript, and modified with javascript, which ultimately will modify the header of the next request sent back to the browser.  All that's happening here is that the cookies section of the request/response headers are being modified, in the server or client.  But you don't run any javascript on your server.

Answer (score 1):

In a controller, you can set a cookie with:

```
cookies['foo'] = 'bar'
```

To set a cookie in Javascript, I wrote a short function in Coffeescript:

```
set_cookie: ( name, value, expiredays = 0 ) ->
  expiredate = new Date()
  expiredate.setDate expiredate.getDate() + expiredays

  expire = '; expires=' + expiredate.toUTCString()

  value = escape( value ) + expire

  document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; path=/'
```